# How to change the spacing between items in a Column or Row

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am aligning `Item`s using `Column` and `Row` types in QML. Is there any way to give different spacing to each `Item`. Something along the line of the following:

**like**:

item1

spacing:10

item2

spacing:20

item3

spacing:40

item4

**here is my code:**

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle{
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent

        Column{
            id: column
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            spacing: 10

            Row{
                id: row1
                anchors.horizontalCenter:  parent.horizontalCenter
                Rectangle{
                    width: 300
                    height: 100
                    color: "lightgreen"
                }
            }
            Row{
                id: row2
                anchors.horizontalCenter:  parent.horizontalCenter
                Rectangle{
                    width: 100
                    height: 50
                    color: "lightblue"
                }
            }
            Row{
                id: row3
                anchors.horizontalCenter:  parent.horizontalCenter
                Rectangle{
                    width: 50
                    height: 50
                    color: "green"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [ColumntLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-columnlayout.html) instead. It has [Layout.topMargin](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#topMargin-attached-prop) attached property to set margins (top one in your case) as well as bottom,right and left ones.

Comment: @folibis write down the answer. That's certainly a good way to solve the issue.

Comment: I agree with @BaCaRoZzo on that.

Comment: @folibis i am following this in many places so so i don't want to change to ColomnLayout. for this can't i use topmargin

Comment: You can use "spacer" `Item`s to have a more fine-grained spacing. Not so practical but it works.

Answer (score 5):

**The hacky version with spacer Items**

Sometimes I prefer this over ColumnLayout since in some situations I just can't use ColumnLayout (can't explain exactly why though at the moment).
I get it working as follows

```
Column {
    Rectangle {
        // ...
    }

    Item {
        width: 1 // dummy value != 0
        height: 10
    }

    Rectangle {
        // ...
    }

    Item {
        width: 1 // dummy value != 0
        height: 20
    }

    Rectangle {
        // ...
    }
}
```

An Item of width 0 won't work. I suggest putting a Spacer_Col.qml (and Spacer_Row analog) into you Toolbox, looking something like

```
import QtQuick 2.8
Item {
    id: root
    property alias spacing: root.height
    width: 1 // dummy value different from 0
}
```

**Using ColumnLayout**

```
ColumnLayout {
    Rectangle{
        // ...
    }

    Rectangle{
        Layout.topMargin: 10
        // ...
    }

    Rectangle{
        Layout.topMargin: 20
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By nesting each rectangle you want to space, as follows;

```
    Row {
        spacing: 20
        Rectangle { color: "red"; width: 50; height: 50 }

        Row {
            spacing: 50
            Rectangle { color: "green"; width: 20; height: 50 }

            Row {
                spacing: 100
                Rectangle { color: "blue"; width: 50; height: 20 }
            }
        }
    }
```

[Different spacings in a row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Wzk.jpg)